# How do I include the original Command and Conquer music in Tiberian Sun?

Tags: command-and-conquer-tiberian-sun

The original Command and Conquer had great music. I don't like Tiberian Sun's score.

How do I include the original Command and Conquer music in Tiberian Sun?

I've tried using XCC tools.

1. I used the XCC Mixer to extract the .AUD files from Scores.mix on the original Command and Conquer CD.
2. Then I used XCC Mix Editor to edit Scores.mix in Tiberian Sun to import the .AUD files. After saving, I can see the .AUD files as well as a file called "local mix database.dat" in the mix file.

But when I start Tiberian Sun, I can't see any of the new .AUD files!

I thought perhaps the format in the 2 games is different. So, then I restored the backup and then:

1. I used the XCC Mixer to extract the AUD files from Scores.mix on the original Command and Conquer CD as .WAV files.
2. Then after selecting Game as Tiberian Sun, I used XCC Mixer to convert the .WAV files to .AUD files.
3. Then I used XCC Mix Editor to edit Scores.mix in Tiberian Sun to import the .AUD files. Again after saving, I can see the AUD files as well as a file called "local mix database.dat" in the mix file.

Still, the game won't play the original Command and Conquer files! Does anyone know how to do it?

Comment: I believe these are just the songs from the game right? If it's just that, I'd go the easy route and just put the music on repeat on some music player and then boot up the game muted. I however have no experience with the way you are trying it.

Comment: There's no need to convert them twice, btw; the aud format of both games is the same.

Answer (score 3):

You need to add a new entry for your new music to the game's internal music list, so the game knows it's a new track, and can give it a name in the playlist and such. Just adding a new .aud file won't work, especially since all of the game's sound effects are also .aud files.

The playlist is one of the ini files inside the game's .mix archives. I believe it's called "theme.ini"